Dockerfile install command for redhat/ubi9-minimal for pgsql
i am moving from base image from debian to redhat/ubi9-minimal due to some critical vulnerable.
can you please help me how to use few command in using in redhat/ubi9-minimal.
easily in debian, i was able to install ksh and libecpg6(ECPG) using command as:
RUN  apt-get install -y ksh && 
apt-get install -y vim && 
apt-get install -y libecpg6
But the same not able to use in redhat/ubi9-minimal with below error:
12 |     RUN microdnf -y update
13 |     RUN microdnf install -y vim
14 | >>> RUN microdnf install -y ksh
15 |     RUN microdnf install -y libecpg6
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c microdnf install -y ksh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1 and same for libecpg6 also. vim able to install but can open any file using vi(file can open using vim <file_name>).
please help and provide your suggestion

please tell me how to install ksh on redhat/ubi9-minimal as base image.
RUN microdnf install -y ksh
above command is not working.

Have you used microdnf repoquery <package> to verify that a package called ksh and libecpg6 exist?
